# codeigniter url routing with query string

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

I have 2 url in my project

http://example.com/one.html

http://example.com/one.html?param1=value&param2=value

In route file I have rules as below

```
$route['search/one?(:any)'] = 'advance_search/books';
$route['search/one'] = 'advance_search/index';
```

when I call 2nd url with query string it still call index method. any one help to fix what is wrong.

Comment: `?` is part of regular expression

Comment: $route['search/one/?(:any)'] = 'advance_search/books'; Also tried like this but not working

Comment: hope my answer helped don't forget to accept it if it did

Answer (score 1):

Try with your route like

```
http://example.com/index.php/controller_name?param1=value&param2=value
```

Controller has to be a php file

Make sure the first letter only is upper case on class and file name.

controllers/One.php

```
<?php

class One extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

      echo $this->input->get('param1');


    }
}
```

If you need to remove index.php try some of these htaccess

https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with something similar, and found that parsing the URL myself offers the most felixibility.

```
public function search() {
    $params = array();
    $url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    parse_str($url['query'], $params);
    // $params now is an array containing the name-value pairs of the querystring. 
    echo("<pre>".print_r($params ,true)."</pre>\n");exit; // for debugging, 
}
```

This went together with the route

```
$route['search/(.+)'] = 'search/search/$1';
```

This dumps all parameters into the search function of the search controller and allows you to handle it as you see fit.